# how to reset page text boxes data after page post back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

my question seems simple  and stupid 
but first read this,
suppose you have a login form which take username and password and post back to controller
if login successful then return Homepage(return View("HomePage")) View (**not Redirect**) then suppose i am Logged off
and return Login (return View("Login")) View (**again not Redirect**) and now if i press Back button and Refresh the page then it will automatically get logged IN by using those username and password which i entered before.
So can i make those password Null from Browser's Memory or where ever it is i don't know.

**"i know that not redirecting (RedirectToAction("ViewName")) is causing the problem" But Why or May be i don't know any important concept**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some browsers, especially Firefox try to be helpful and 'remember' values you have input into text fields and checkboxes.  in order to switch this off in a particular input add the following attribute

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Alternatively, using jQuery you can switch it off for a whole form:

```
$("form").attr("autocomplete", "off");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ModelState.Remove("key");
```

or

```
ModelState.Clear()
```